# Need to track my app's foreground and background status

Tags: android, android-intent

I know this question is not new to stackoverflow, however I am still confused. So please don't mark this question as a duplicate, help me on this!

My android app has many activities. I need to call a web service, when my app comes to foreground and need to call another web service, when my app switched to background.

My initial findings are:

- I read the activity life cycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle and realized that I can call the above 2 web services in
- onPause() = when app is switched to background
- onResume() = when app is switched to foreground.

**My activity:**

```
  protected void onPause() 
    {
        AppUtil.trackAppBackgroundStatus(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        AppUtil.trackAppForegroundStatus(this);
    }
```

**My utility class:**

```
public class AppUtil 
{
    public static void trackAppForegroundStatus(Context theContext)
    {
        SharedPreferences aSharedSettings = theContext.getSharedPreferences("MyAppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String aAppStatus = aSharedSettings.getString("appStatus", "");

        if(!aAppStatus.equals("foreground"))
        {       
            SharedPreferences.Editor aPrefEditor = aSharedSettings.edit();
            aPrefEditor.putString("appStatus", "foreground");
            aPrefEditor.commit();

            trackSession(theContext, "foreground");
        }
    }

    public static void trackAppBackgroundStatus(Context theContext)
    {
        SharedPreferences aSharedSettings = theContext.getSharedPreferences("MyAppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String aAppStatus = aSharedSettings.getString("appStatus", "");

        if(!aAppStatus.equals("background"))
        {   
            SharedPreferences.Editor aPrefEditor = aSharedSettings.edit();
            aPrefEditor.putString("appStatus", "background");
            aPrefEditor.commit();

            trackSession(theContext, "background");
        }
    }
}
```

The trackSession method will track my app's foreground and background status.

**Drawbacks:**
As said above, my app has various activities. So consider I have Page_A and Page_B.

In Page_A, after the onCreate() method call, control goes to onResume() and tracks that my app is in foreground.. When I move to the next page (Page_B), onPause() method of Page_A is called and tracks that my app is switched to background.

I don't want to track this by every activities.. I need to track my app's background status only when my app goes to background (that is, only when user presses home button and my app is switched to background).

- I also tried with [Checking if an Android application is running in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background/5862048#5862048) and the same happens
- **getRunningTasks()** will solve my issue. However read that, Google will probably reject an app that uses ActivityManager.getRunningTasks().

Can anyone please guide me. Basically, I need to call 2 web-services. One, when app comes to foreground and the second, when app switches to background.

If these calls cannot be made with respect to app, how can I update my above code to handle them.

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
    // application is on background
}
```

In the documentation of Acitivity.onUserLeaveHint() you can find the following

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to
>   go into the background as the result of user choice. For example, when
>   the user presses the Home key, onUserLeaveHint() will be called, but
>   when an incoming phone call causes the in-call Activity to be
>   automatically brought to the foreground, onUserLeaveHint() will not be
>   called on the activity being interrupted. In cases when it is invoked,
>   this method is called right before the activity's onPause() callback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply StinePike. I tried this.. Even during page change (that is from Page_A to Page_B), onUserLeaveHint() is called. During the page change, I think the control goes in the following order. (1) onUserLeaveHint().. (2) onPause().. (3) onStop().. As I said above, I need to track the background event only when app goes to background (but not during page change). Suggestions please..

Comment: I think you can do one thing just an experimental suggestion. after onpause save state like you did before then at the end of onPause set a  postdelayed runnable say for 1 second. at that runnable first check the applcation state that you are saving. If the application state is background then you know the total application is in background

Answer (score 0):

As you said,

- getRunningTasks() will solve my issue. However read that, Google will probably reject an app that uses ActivityManager.getRunningTasks().

but have a look at [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html)

```
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
            if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.your.package.name")) {
//              procInfos.get(i).IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your app is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Mehul Joisar. Can you please suggest me where should I put the above code to check?

Answer (score 0):

If min API level is 14 then [Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks%28android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks%29) method will solve this task easily. Just count active activities in "onActivityPaused" and "onActivityResumed" methods by incrementing/decrementing some value. So non zero value will indicate that application is in foreground.